# Convert SQL update query to json request

Tags: php, sql, json

I have an sql update query like this; please note that I just have a string of the query like $query:

```
$query = 'UPDATE "public"."activity" SET "itemid" = 2, "itemname" = 'sssd' WHERE "id" = 19';
```

From this stringified query, I can get the set clause separately as:

```
$setClause = '"itemid" = 2, "itemname" = 'sssd'';
```

I need to convert this set clause to a json array to send in an ajax request like:

```
{
    "itemid": 2,
    "itemname": "sssd"
  }
```

So far I havent been able to figure this out; I looked online for a solution as well but couldn't find one. Any ideas please?

Comment: What's the purpose of converting the query to JSON? Reading the question it seems like there's probably something you can be doing other than this in the first place to achieve your goal. Can you give more details?

Comment: @JohnHalbert Sure, I am modifying an application that connects directly to a database also work via a restful web service. I have found the php code where the sql query is generated and executed and i am trying to use that part to make the app connect to the web service. please note that I need both the database connection and web service connection to keep working. Also I am not expected to change the existing code as much as possible.

Comment: So, please correct me if I'm not understanding, you'd like to convert incoming JSON from AJAX request to allow you to change your query dynamically?  If that's the case, please be aware of SQL injection, and possibly look at json_decode() method for php.

Comment: no. I just want to send the sql request (which database is in the same server) + a request to the webservice generated from the same query. :)

Comment: `$sc2JSON = '{' . str_replace('=', ':', $setClause) . '}'` ??

Comment: that is great. With a little modification the job is done! thanks a lot. Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This did the job for me. Thanks to [John Halbert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4702606/john-halbert) for pointing it out in the comments.

```
public function GetJsonFromUpdateSetClause($setClause){
        $sc2JSON1 = '{' . str_replace('=', ':', $setClause) . '}';
        $sc2JSON2 =  str_replace('\'', '\"', $sc2JSON1) ;
        $sc2JSON3 = stripcslashes($sc2JSON2);
        return $sc2JSON3;
    }
```